# Можно ли как-нибудь вшить файл в программу

Tags: c#

c# Есть программа (FindUpdateCMD.exe), которая находится в папке с моей программой (Weather.exe). В Weather.exe происходит включение FindUpdateCMD.exe, получение данных из неё и тп. Можно ли как-нибудь программу FindUpdateCMD.exe "вшить" в основную программу и в дальнейшем использовать её, например, временно распаковывая в папку с программой и потом удаляя?

Comment: Добавьте в ресурсы, она будет храниться там в виде байтов. Когда надо просто скопировали байты на диск, сделали что надо и удалили в конце (если надо).

Comment: А как после компиляции обращаться к этому файлу?

Comment: [How to read embedded resource text file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3314213/312041)

Comment: Огромное спасибо!